# How to install scikit-learn in SageMath 9.3 Notebook in a Windows device?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have used scikit learn on my Windows device for Jupyter Notebooks without any problem, but I need to use SageMath 9.3 for a university course and I tried to use `%pip install scikit-learn` and `%pip install -U scikit-learn` commands in a SageMath noteook but it's not working. Apparently nobody in my class using windows has been able to (as of two weeks ago), works fine on MacOS. My searches didn't yield anything useful, is it possible to install the library?

Partial error log as the whole thing is too big

````
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.2.tar.gz (6.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/bin/python3 /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-nphjkzbm/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools<60.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'oldest-supported-numpy; python_version!='"'"'3.7'"'"' or platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"' or platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"' or platform_python_implementation == '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.6; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (9617 lines):
  Ignoring oldest-supported-numpy: markers 'python_version != "3.7" or platform_machine == "aarch64" or platform_system == "AIX" or platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools<60.0
    Using cached setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
    Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.14.6
    Using cached numpy-1.14.6-cp37-cp37m-cygwin_3_2_0_x86_64.whl
  Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
    Using cached scipy-1.7.3.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Using cached scipy-1.7.2.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Using cached scipy-1.7.1.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/bin/python3 /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpqr8ur2nx
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0b3d_b3u/scipy_b5491a6e79864d5bbc6400ba8769f139
      Complete output (159 lines):
      Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
      Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
      Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
      Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
      Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
      Processing scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx
      Processing scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx
      Processing scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
      Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
      Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
      Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
      Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
      Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
      Processing scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx
      Processing scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx
      Processing scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx
      Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
      Processing scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx
      Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx
      Processing scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx
      Processing scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx
      Processing scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx
      Processing scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx
      Processing scipy/spatial/transform/rotation.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
      Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/biasedurn.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_stats.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
      Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:9:8: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:13:4: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:21:8: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:25:4: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:33:8: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:37:4: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:45:8: Unreachable code
      warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:49:4: Unreachable code
      Cythonizing sources
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
 

        openblas_lapack_info:
         customize UnixCCompiler
         customize UnixCCompiler
         customize UnixCCompiler
         C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python37/python37-3.7.10-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python37-3.7.10-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python37/python37-3.7.10-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python37-3.7.10-2 -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python37/python37-3.7.10-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python37-3.7.10-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python37/python37-3.7.10-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python37-3.7.10-2
      
          creating /tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/tmp
          creating /tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki
          compile options: '-c'
          gcc: /tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/source.c
          gcc /tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/source.o -L/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib -lopenblas.dll -o /tmp/tmp1hu6a0ki/a.out.exe
          customize UnixCCompiler
            FOUND:
              libraries = ['openblas.dll', 'openblas.dll']
              library_dirs = ['/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib']
              language = c
              define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      
            FOUND:
              libraries = ['openblas.dll', 'openblas.dll']
              library_dirs = ['/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib']
              language = c
              define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      
          setup.py:492: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-3rq4dd3a'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
            ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))
          Running from SciPy source directory.
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 788, in get
              value = d[option]
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 916, in __getitem__
              return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 908, in __missing__
              raise KeyError(key)
          KeyError: 'defines'
      
          During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
              main()
            File "/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
            File "/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
              return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
              self.run_setup()
    
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 259, in run_setup
              self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
              exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
            File "setup.py", line 629, in <module>
              setup_package()
            File "setup.py", line 625, in setup_package
              setup(**metadata)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
              config = configuration()
            File "setup.py", line 536, in configuration
              config.add_subpackage('scipy')
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
              caller_level = 2)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
              caller_level = caller_level + 1)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
              config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
            File "scipy/setup.py", line 12, in configuration
              config.add_subpackage('interpolate')
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
              caller_level = 2)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
              caller_level = caller_level + 1)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
              config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
            File "scipy/interpolate/setup.py", line 62, in configuration
              config=['compiler.blas=none']
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythran/dist.py", line 145, in __init__
              cfg_ext = cfg.make_extension(python=True, **kwargs)
            File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hwqkwf0i/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythran/config.py", line 139, in make_extension
              cfg.get('compiler', 'defines').split()],
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 791, in get
              raise NoOptionError(option, section)
          configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'defines' in section: 'compiler'
          ----------------------------------------
      WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/33/a24aec22b7be7fdb10ec117a95e1e4099890d8bbc6646902f443fc7719d1/scipy-1.7.1.tar.gz#sha256=6b47d5fa7ea651054362561a28b1ccc8da9368a39514c1bbf6c0977a1c376764 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:>=3.7,<3.10). Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/bin/python3 /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpqr8ur2nx Check the logs for full command output.
        Using cached scipy-1.7.0.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
          Preparing wheel metadata: started
          Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
          Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
           command: /opt/sagemath-9.3/local/bin/python3 `/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpwoujhuuk`
               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0b3d_b3u/scipy_54bc3010242246889b2403d28ea21946
          Complete output (159 lines):```
````

Comment: Were there any error messages?  What happens if you try `!python -m pip install scikit-learn`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs this command doesn't work either. attaching the  error log

Comment: Strange there are so many versions of `scipy` that are trying to be installed.  I wonder if the older versions are removed if the `scikit-learn` install might progress further.